# JS/JQuery: How to switch class several times in a loop way?

Tags: jquery, css, class, if-statement

How to switch several times the class of an item in a loopy way ?
I tried various combinations of the following a 1/3 success. The first switch-click works (news->part), the second click doesn't (part->easy), the 3rd doesn't (easy->news). Thanks by advance.

**HTML**

```
<td class="news">Click on me!<td>
<td class="news">Click on me too!<td>
```

***CSS***

```
.news { border: 3px solid red ; }
.part { border: 3px solid orange ; }
.easy { border: 3px solid green ; }
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$("td").click(function () {
  if (        $("td").hasClass('news')) {
    $(this).removeClass("news").addClass('part');   /* click 1: works*/
  } else if ( $("td").hasClass('part')) {
    $(this).removeClass('part'  ).addClass('easy'); /* click 2: doesn't*/
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass('easy'  ).addClass('news'); /* click 2: doesn't*/
  }
});
```

Comment: Why the large spaces in the `removeClass('')` bit? It seems that your code is weirdly formatted... also, do you mind providing a JSFiddle? Please edit your question. Thanks. :)

Comment: Since I was looking for a little typo mistake, I added the spaces to align all similar items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Javascript**

```
$("td").click(function () {
  if ($(this).hasClass('news')) {
    $(this).removeClass("news").addClass('part');   /* click 1: works*/
  } else if ( $(this).hasClass('part')) {
    $(this).removeClass('part'  ).addClass('easy'); /* click 2: doesn't*/
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass('easy'  ).addClass('news'); /* click 2: doesn't*/
  }
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/sRvcK/

Comment: Thanks Kevin for both the solution and Fiddle.

Comment: @Hugolpz Glad I could help.  Thanks for posting a solid question!

Answer (score 0):

In if block you should use `this` as well instead of `$("td").hasClass('news')`, as below

```
if ($(this).hasClass('news')) {
   //Do your thing...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("td").click(function () {

  var $this = $(this);

  if ($this.hasClass('news')) {

    $this.removeClass('news').addClass('part');

  } else if ($this.hasClass('part')) {

    $this.removeClass('part').addClass('easy');

  } else {

    $this.removeClass('easy').addClass('news');

  }
});
```

Comment: I prefered Kevin proposal because there is no real gain to create a  'var $this = $(this);' which just save 2 characters each time, but add a degree of abstraction not need in this small code. But yet, thanks for your help!

Comment: Actually, the savings is in only retrieving the element once instead of five times. May not matter much for what you're doing, but it is good practice.

Comment: What do you mean: your script-practice will run faster ?